# Recommended way to iterate through a collection of types of a typeclass that have nothing in common?

Tags: scala, typeclass

I'm learning about type-classes from Atomic Scala. I understand the purpose of type-classes (in that you have inheritance relationships dedicated to functionality rather than placing them on the type itself which lets you have extensible systems) but the book poses an interesting question.

In traditional polymorphism, your types are bound by the inheritance hierarchy. Therefore, if you have a Shape and Circle, Triangle, etc. extend shape, it is valid to have a Vector of `Shapes` like `Vector(Circle, Triangle, ...)`.

However, there is no relation between types when using the type-class pattern. So a Vector(Circle, Triangle) would just be a Vector of `Serializable`. The way I managed to use the type-class method (`areaForShape`) is to use pattern matching to drill down and resolve specific types so the type-class method can infer the right type and the correct typeclass implementation can be injected.

Is there a better way to approach this kind of iteration?

```
import scala.math.{sqrt, Pi}

// type-class functionality we want to have applied
// to existing types without touching their internals
trait Calc[S] {
  def area(shape: S): Double
}
// type-class method
def areaForShape[S](shape: S)(implicit calc: Calc[S]) =
  calc.area(shape)

// specific CircleCalc implementation of the type-class
// injected into environment that implements area of a Circle
implicit object CircleCalc extends Calc[Circle] {
  override def area(shape: Circle): Double = 2 * Pi * shape.radius
}

// specific EQLTriangleCalc implementation of the type-class
// injected into environment that implements area of an EQLTriangle
implicit object EQLTriangleCalc extends Calc[EQLTriangle] {
  override def area(shape: EQLTriangle): Double = (sqrt(3)/4) * shape.side * shape.side
}

case class Circle(radius: Double)
case class EQLTriangle(side: Double)

Vector(Circle(1), EQLTriangle(3)).map{
  case c: Circle => areaForShape(c)
  case t: EQLTriangle => areaForShape(t)
}
```

Comment: In general as a design principle I'd say that if you're sure you need a homogeneous collection of different kinds of things, inheritance might be a better solution. It might be the case that something like Shapeless's `HList` (or just a plain old n-tuple) might be a better fit, though.

Comment: If you could perhaps post a snippet, that would be awesome

Comment: As Travis Brown already said, using inheritance might be a better solution here. Alternatively, if you prefer to keep the `areaForShape` functionality separate from your concrete shape classes, maybe [the visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is what you're looking for. (That would still require that all your shapes extend some type that provides an `accept(v: ShapeVisitor)` method, but that might be an acceptable tradeoff.)